# systemd-journal is using 100% cpu

Tags: debian, cpu, systemd-journald, journalctl

This is the result of `top` command

[image]

I caught it at 99.7% but It even uses 170%.  this is the output of `journalctl`

[image]

I thought it is something related to Bluetooth, so I turned it off but still got the same output. Cput usage rate gets lower, sound of cpu gets lower but then it starts again.

Comment: if you watch the journal with `journalctl -f` is there lots of output?  I certainly seems like pulseaudio that is sitting at 123 minutes of cpu time is the culprit to me.

Comment: Running `journalctl -f` helped me, thanks.  I found lots of messages there related to `tumblerd`, some assertion check was failing.  After killing tumblerd, the high cpu issue was resolved.